Как настроить правило tsconfig для отдельной папки?
У меня есть бибилиотека test в node_mobules, которая требует сборки (там ts нужно в js преобразовывать и т.д.). Но при этом файлы библиотеки из node_mobules линтить не нужно. Но сейчас, при сборки они проверяются и выводится ошибки, что в библиотеки из node_mobules есть не используемые переменные.
В webpack у меня установлено вот такое правило
rules: [
  {
    test: /\.ts$/,
    loader: 'ts-loader',
    exclude: [
      /node_modules(?!\/test)/,
    ],
    options: {
      onlyCompileBundledFiles: true,
    },
  },

Если вместо  /node_modules(?!/test)/, указать просто  /node_modules/, то ошибки об неипользуемых переменных в библиотеки test пропадает, но т.к. после этого файлы из библиотеки test попадают в исключение и больше не транформируются 'ts-loader' то появляются ошибки сборки т.к. в библиотеки test тайпскриптовые файлы и их нужно собирать.
Ещё есть файл tsconfig:{ "compilerOptions": { "target": "es5", "module": "esnext", "strict": true, "jsx": "preserve", "importHelpers": true, "moduleResolution": "node", "sourceMap": true, "baseUrl": ".", "noUnusedLocals": true, "lib": [ "esnext", "dom", "dom.iterable", "scripthost" ] }, "exclude": [ "node_modules", ] }
Если noUnusedLocals перевести в false, то ошибки об не используемых переменных пропадают. Но проблема в том, что не используемые переменные перестают проверяться для всего проекта, а не только для библиотек из node_modules. Подскажите, как сделать, что бы он node_module не првоерял, а годовую базу проекта продолжал бы проверять на не используемые переменные?
